# Avengers: Endgame timeline and causality

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*,

> if Thanos from 2014 was dusted in 2023 by Iron Man's snap, then how did the Thanos other 'snap' in 2018?

Does this imply that

> there is a branch reality where they never bring back everyone with Professor Hulk's snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Professor Hulk meant by his long speech in the lab is, traveling into the past creates a new reality; the old one still exists. Thus, the Grandfather Paradox can't happen. This is not the same as most Star Trek time travel stories, or Back to the Future.

> The 2014 Thanos that was killed in 2023, is NOT the SAME Thanos as the
>  one who did the Snap; in the reality the 2014 Thanos was from, the
>  Snap would never happen so there would be nobody to save. The hard
>  thing to understand is, somehow Tony Stark figured out how to bring
>  the Avengers back to their original reality when they traveled
>  forward. Thus, the Infinity gems were brought to the reality where the
>  Snap had happened, and they could be used to undo it.
>  
>  So, it's like this. There was a Thanos in the reality in which the
>  time traveling didn't happen. He's the one who gathered all the
>  Infinity Gems, did the Snap, killed half of everybody. Then he
>  disintegrated the stones, and got his head chopped off by Thor. Five
>  years later, the remaining Avengers travel into the past, thus
>  creating a different reality, where a different version of Thanos
>  finds out about their plans. The Avengers return to their original
>  future, which was still affected by the first Thanos we knew about.
>  Then the bad Nebula pulls the second Thanos across realities into the
>  one where half of everyone is dead, and the latter part of the movie
>  occurs.

Comment: It's not a quote; this isn't what Professor Hulk said, it's my explanation of what Professor Hulk said. it contains spoilers (just as the question does) so I marked it as a spoiler.